# how can I transfer multiple tables from postgresql database to csv file using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have tried to transfer a table from PostgreSQL to csv with pandas and it was success. But when I tried to transfer multiple tables from a database to csv I am getting errors. please explain how to transfer multiple tables from PostgreSQL to csv files at a time.

Comment: what kind of errors, can you describe what are you doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.